# Compatibility jquery with IE - click function and fade

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Here my script : http://jsfiddle.net/3XwZv/153/

**HTML**

```
<div id="box1" class="choice" style="background:blue;">
    <div class="selection ordinateur">
        <div class="choix1"><a class="link1" href="#"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="box2" class="choice" style="display:none;background:red;">
    <div class="selection ordinateur">
        <div class="choix1"><a class="link2" href="#"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="box3" class="choice" style="display:none;background:green;">
    <div class="selection ordinateur">
        <div class="choix1"><a href="#"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".link1").click(function() {
    $('#box1').fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $('#box2').css("display","block");
        $('#box2').replaceWith(div);

       $('#box1').fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $('.link1').fadeOut("slow");
    return false;
});


$(".link2").click(function() {
    $('#box2').fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $('#box3').css("display","block");
        $('#box3').replaceWith(div);

       $('#box2').fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $('.link2').fadeOut("slow");
    return false;
});
```

The main goal is that when you click on the giant square, I have three differents action. However, in Internet Explorer I block to the second. (the red square does not go to the green square). 
Please I need your help guys!

Comment: Which internet explorer are you using?

Comment: Try putting something _inside_ your `<a></a>` tags, like a `&nbsp;`.  Some versions of IE will ignore your CSS and treat an empty `<a>` as zero in size.  Better yet, just delete the `<a>` tags entirely and instead target the `<div>`'s with your `click()` handlers... that's what `click()` is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the div visibility by showing and hiding it using jquery `show()` and `hide()` functions. I updated the fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/VP8ub/2/

Hope that's what you need. I tested in IE9 and its working well.